# Fast way Transfer Java object on Network

Tags: java, deserialization, network-protocols

I have a thrift server which is serving Java objects to clients and these Java objects are stored in Membase.while serving client most of the time is going in serialization and deserialization of object. In membase we save a byte stream. I wanted to ask If I can skip in any way deserialization of the object ? Give the object as is to client which is also in Java.

Is there any other way we can transfer of object on wire ?

Comment: So you are sending serialized Java objects like `Server -> Membase -> Client`, and the goal is to avoid having `Membase` deserialize/reserialize the objects on their way to the client?

Comment: My call is Server(1)->Membase->Server(2)->client. Using memebase just to have fast access the Java object. I want to deserialization on the Server(2) end

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own marshall/umarshall mechanism or use one of the existing as an alternative to serialization/deserialization.

There are pros and cons for both approaches (**marshalling** and **serialization**).

It is hard to say what is preferred in your case, without knowing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your client program and server program is running in different javaw.exe i.e with different JVM .So,to communicate data between different java program with two processes you need serilization and deserilization.You can not escape it.